# Low idle and tacho twitching after electrical cut out

Tags: electrical, golf, rough-idle

The car is a 93 VW Cabriolet (Mk1 Golf/Rabbit).

I was parked with the engine on lowering the hydro/electric roof when the engine and power cut out. I couldn't restart the car so checked the battery and fuses - all fine, so I tried again. This time the car did start but now is idling very low, sputters a bit and the tacho twitches. Feels fine to drive - this seems to just happen at idle.

Have I blown some electrics? Fuel pump relay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to check the engine bay while the car was running and immediately noticed a bright continuos spark on one of the battery terminals. Turned of car and went to fix it but the terminal was almost red hot and burnt my fingers.

Eventually I managed to clean the terminal again and tighten some of the wiring eyelets (ammeter connection) that were attached to it. Cars been running fine since.